# Dataframe group by value, remove duplicates, but save non similar entries? Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to scan through a dataframe in python to create a new dataframe that groups by a certain column, removes duplicates, while simultaneously saving none-similar entries, say into a list?

So if I have a dataframe that looks something like this...

```
Genre     Rating   CustomRating
Thriller  5        5
Thriller  5        5
Comedy    9        9
Action    3        6
Action    2        7
```

I need it to turn into something like this...

```
Genre     Rating   CustomRating
Thriller  5        5
Comedy    9        9
Action    3, 2     6, 7
```

**progress updates**

@ignoring_gravity suggestion work of doing `df.drop_duplicates().groupby('Genre', sort=False).agg(list)` worked great, but is there a way of returning items as say a string or int rather than a list?

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected output in the case of an additional row with `Thriller, 5, 6`? It's unclear what constitutes a "duplicate"

Comment: @ALollz in that case that row would look...         `Thriller`    `5`    `5 ,6`              where the `Raiting` scored is the same, but the `CustomRating` has noted the two different scores.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do `groupby` and then `agg`:

```
df.groupby('Genre', sort=False).agg(lambda x: list(set(x))).reset_index()
```

and you'll get

```
      Genre  Rating CustomRating
0  Thriller     [5]          [5]
1    Comedy     [9]          [9]
2    Action  [2, 3]       [6, 7]
```

Comment: That worked great.  Is there a way to also do this where it will return either a string or an int rather a list?

Comment: @rwjam I think replacing the aggregate function with `lambda x: ', '.join([str(i) for i in list(set(x))])` should work, can you try that?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is none by default. You can use `groupby` followed by an `agg` and create a `list` as suggested by others. However, there is a good reason this is discouraged ;)

Your second DataFrame is extemely difficult to work with. You can never now whether it contains a single value or a list. This goes against the whole idea of a DataFrame. Also you loose information. How many action movies where there? Did the custom rating 6 have a rating of 2 or 3. You can't answer these questions anymore. What would you do next? Calculate a summary statistic? Then just directly use `groupby().mean()`, `groupby().std()` or whatever you need? Plot that? There even is a `groupby().plot()`.

If you are tempted to do something like that, that is a telltale sign you should think about why you need that. The general pattern in pandas is called split-apply-combine. You are trying to only do the split part. I advice you to only to do that when you have a very good reason to do so.

Comment: "You can never now whether it contains a single value or a list." it'll always contain a list

Comment: The way he framed the question, he was mixing scalar values and collections. And you can actually do this with `apply` if you want to. But indeed, with your solution it is always a list and I agree that this is the better solution.